# Kusto convert string to date

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-log-analytics

Writing a kusto query I have a date time format of yyyyMMdd HHmmss.SSS eg: 20230726 121033.000.  When using the todatetime I am unable to convert the format to date/time.

project todatetime(['TimeStamp_s']) does not return any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yyyyMMdd HHmmss.SSS` is not supported format. Refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/datetime#supported-formats) for the supported formats in Kusto datetime() function.

```
let MyTable = datatable(TimeStamp_s:string, OtherColumn1:string, OtherColumn2:string)
[
    '20230726 121033.000', 'Value1', 'Value2',
    '20230727 093015.123', 'Value3', 'Value4',
    '20230728 184500.999', 'Value5', 'Value6'
];
MyTable
| project todatetime(strcat(substring(['TimeStamp_s'],0,4),'-',substring(['TimeStamp_s'],4,2),'-',substring(['TimeStamp_s'],6,2),'T',substring(['TimeStamp_s'],9,2),':',substring(['TimeStamp_s'],11,2),':',substring(['TimeStamp_s'],13,6)))
```

The `substring()` function is used to extract the year, month, day, hour, minute, and second components from the `TimeStamp_s` string, and the `strcat()` function is used to concatenate them into a string. This way, format is changed to  ISO 8601 datetime format and given as input to `todatetime()` function.